# Set Text all EditText at once

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment

I have a fragment with about 30 `EditText` inside it. I want to know is there any way to grab all `EditTexts` and clear the text inside it without doing it one by one.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if all your edittexts are within the same layout, for example a relativelayout

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_group);
for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
    View view = group.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)view).setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTextsList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

for( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++ )
  if( myLayout.getChildAt( i ) instanceof EditText )
    editTextsList.add( (EditText) myLayout.getChildAt( i ) );
```

The iterate on `editTextsList` and do your actions on each of `EditText` on the list

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do with the following method.

```
public void clearStudentInfo(ViewGroup textViewsGroup) {       
    for (int i = 0, count = textViewsGroup.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
        View view = textViewsGroup.getChildAt(i);
        // Check and confirm, is it is the TextView or not?
        if (textViewsGroup instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText)textViewsGroup).setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

You can call the method when you click on clear button as given below.

```
...

Button btnClear = findViewById(R.id.btnClr);

...

btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) {
    @Override
    void onClick(...) {
        clearStudentInfo((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.student_info));
}
```

Thanks